# Controlling firefox add-on sdk sidebar width

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-sidebar

I am creating a firefox add-on with [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK). My add-on uses a sidebar created with the [ui/sidebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar) API. Is there any way for me to control the initial width of this sidebar?

The user can drag to change its size, but I would like it to start with a greater width than it seems to open at by default. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using [window/utils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils) you can get the topmost browser window as an [nsIDOMWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindow) instance, then you can get the sidebar element of that window as an HTML element, which would enable you to modify it's CSS properties:

```
var utils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var win = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
if (utils.isBrowser (win))
{
    var sidebar = win.document.getElementById ("sidebar");
    sidebar.style.minWidth = "340px";
    sidebar.style.width = "340px";
    sidebar.style.maxWidth = "500px";
}
```

**Note that** this will affect all sidebars of the topmost open firefox window (including bookmarks and history sidebars);

Answer (score 0):

Yes use width in the style attribute. Or use min-width.
Like `style: 'min-width: 14em; width: 18em; max-width: 36em;'`

Here is an addon that creates a sidebar. You can install it, its a ready to go demo. [_ff-addon-BootstrapSidebar](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8728393)

Comment: Which style attribute are you referencing? I'm new to firefox add-ons, but it looks like the example you provided was for a bootstraped extension. My project uses the add-on sdk. Can I set this attribute from within the SDK? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I missed that. In SDK I'm not sure.

Comment: I see no one has replied to this still. See this addon it is bootstrap, but a simple template to show you about sidebar: [_ff-addon-template-BootstrapSidebar](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8728393) the width is controlled in this one